# Why when using backgroundworker with while loop it's taking like 2-3 seconds to show when running the program?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I think the problem is the while loop.
When running the program it's taking like 2-3 seconds until I see the form1 and all the values and everything running fine. Is there any way to make it to start showing faster ?

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

namespace Ssystem_Usage
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        private PerformanceCounter cpuCounter;
        private PerformanceCounter ramCounter;
        private object[] CurrentStatus = new object[5];

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            InitialiseCPUCounter();
            backgroundWorker1.RunWorkerAsync();

        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void InitialiseCPUCounter()
        {
            cpuCounter = new PerformanceCounter(
            "Processor",
            "% Processor Time",
            "_Total",
            true
            );
        }

        private void InitializeRAMCounter()
        {
            ramCounter = new PerformanceCounter("Memory", "Available MBytes", true);

        }

        private void SystemUsage()
        {
            while (true)
            {
                Int64 phav = PerformanceInfo.GetPhysicalAvailableMemoryInMiB();
                Int64 tot = PerformanceInfo.GetTotalMemoryInMiB();
                decimal percentFree = ((decimal)phav / (decimal)tot) * 100;
                decimal percentOccupied = 100 - percentFree;
                string CpuUsage = Convert.ToInt32(cpuCounter.NextValue()).ToString();
                CurrentStatus[0] = phav;
                CurrentStatus[1] = tot;
                CurrentStatus[2] = percentFree;
                CurrentStatus[3] = percentOccupied;
                CurrentStatus[4] = CpuUsage;
                backgroundWorker1.ReportProgress(0, CurrentStatus);
                System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(500);
            }
        }

        private void backgroundWorker1_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
        {
            SystemUsage();
        }

        private void backgroundWorker1_ProgressChanged(object sender, ProgressChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            if (typeof(object[]) == e.UserState.GetType())
            {
                object[] StatusMsg = (object[])e.UserState;
                if (5 == StatusMsg.GetLength(0))
                {

                    if (StatusMsg[0] != null)
                    {
                        label3.Text = "Available Physical Memory (MiB) ";
                        textBox3.Text = StatusMsg[0].ToString();
                    }
                    if (StatusMsg[1] != null)
                    {
                        label4.Text = "Total Memory (MiB) ";
                        textBox4.Text = StatusMsg[1].ToString();
                    }
                    if (StatusMsg[2] != null)
                    {
                        label5.Text = "Free (%) ";
                        textBox5.Text = StatusMsg[2].ToString();
                    }
                    if (StatusMsg[3] != null)
                    {
                        label6.Text = "Occupied (%) ";
                        textBox6.Text = StatusMsg[3].ToString();
                    }
                    if (StatusMsg[4] != null)
                    {
                        this.textBox1.Text = "CPU Usage: " +
                        StatusMsg[4] +
                        "%";
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        private void backgroundWorker1_RunWorkerCompleted(object sender, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e)
        {

        }

        public static class PerformanceInfo
        {
            [DllImport("psapi.dll", SetLastError = true)]
            [return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
            public static extern bool GetPerformanceInfo([Out] out PerformanceInformation PerformanceInformation, [In] int Size);

            [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
            public struct PerformanceInformation
            {
                public int Size;
                public IntPtr CommitTotal;
                public IntPtr CommitLimit;
                public IntPtr CommitPeak;
                public IntPtr PhysicalTotal;
                public IntPtr PhysicalAvailable;
                public IntPtr SystemCache;
                public IntPtr KernelTotal;
                public IntPtr KernelPaged;
                public IntPtr KernelNonPaged;
                public IntPtr PageSize;
                public int HandlesCount;
                public int ProcessCount;
                public int ThreadCount;
            }

            public static Int64 GetPhysicalAvailableMemoryInMiB()
            {
                PerformanceInformation pi = new PerformanceInformation();
                if (GetPerformanceInfo(out pi, Marshal.SizeOf(pi)))
                {
                    return Convert.ToInt64((pi.PhysicalAvailable.ToInt64() * pi.PageSize.ToInt64() / 1048576));
                }
                else
                {
                    return -1;
                }

            }

            public static Int64 GetTotalMemoryInMiB()
            {
                PerformanceInformation pi = new PerformanceInformation();
                if (GetPerformanceInfo(out pi, Marshal.SizeOf(pi)))
                {
                    return Convert.ToInt64((pi.PhysicalTotal.ToInt64() * pi.PageSize.ToInt64() / 1048576));
                }
                else
                {
                    return -1;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you confident that it's not the `InitialiseCPUCounter` call taking 2-3 seconds? It takes a little over 1,000 ms on my i7 during a cold run. If that's the culprit, call `InitialiseCPUCounter` at the very beginning of `SystemUsage`, before you enter the loop.

Answer (score 1):

There are two options:

1. Run the `backgroundWorker.RunWorkerAsync()` on the `Shown` and not on the `Load` event. If this doesn't help:
2. Why are you using while(true)? A timer would be way better.

To prevent an error first add a variable to the class (maybe `private bool bwrunning = false;`)

Then edit the DoWork Method as follows:

```
private void backgroundWorker1_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
    {
        bwrunning = true;
        SystemUsage();
    }
```

Delete the while:

```
private void SystemUsage()
    {
        Int64 phav = PerformanceInfo.GetPhysicalAvailableMemoryInMiB();
        Int64 tot = PerformanceInfo.GetTotalMemoryInMiB();
        decimal percentFree = ((decimal)phav / (decimal)tot) * 100;
        decimal percentOccupied = 100 - percentFree;
        string CpuUsage = Convert.ToInt32(cpuCounter.NextValue()).ToString();
        CurrentStatus[0] = phav;
        CurrentStatus[1] = tot;
        CurrentStatus[2] = percentFree;
        CurrentStatus[3] = percentOccupied;
        CurrentStatus[4] = CpuUsage;
        backgroundWorker1.ReportProgress(0, CurrentStatus);
        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(500);
    }
```

Edit oncompleted:

```
private void backgroundWorker1_RunWorkerCompleted(object sender, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e)
        {
            bwrunning = false;
        }
```

And at least add the `timer1_tick` method:

```
private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if(bwrunning)
        {
            backgroundWorker1.RunWorkerAsync();
        }
    }
```

If you set `timer1.Enable = true` and the Delay if you want it, it should be way faster.